# Flutter: erorr al correr la app Execution failed for task ':app:compressDebugAssets'

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Necesito ayuda en algo que puede parecer muy simple pero que no me deja continuar

no se por qué no me corre la app sin haberle cambiado nada
probé esto:

- `flutter run`
- `flutter packages upgrade`
- `run in debug mode`
- `flutter clean`
- `flutter doctor`
- volvi a mi ultimo commit
- reinicie vs code
- reinicie equipo

pero nada me ha servido, y me salen cosas fuera de lugar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:compressDebugAssets'.

> java.io.IOException: Unable to delete directory 'C:\flutter_project\cursin2\LoginFlutter-master\build\app\intermediates\compressed_assets\debug\out'

```
Failed to delete some children. This might happen because a process has files open or has its working directory set in the target directory.

- C:\flutter_project\cursin2\LoginFlutter-master\build\app\intermediates\compressed_assets\debug\out\assets\flutter_assets\assets\icon

- C:\flutter_project\cursin2\LoginFlutter-master\build\app\intermediates\compressed_assets\debug\out\assets\flutter_assets\packages\font_awesome_flutter
```

- Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 2m 20s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            144,4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
PS C:\flutter_project\cursin2\LoginFlutter-master>

Comment: Intenta borrar el directorio, C:\flutter_project\cursin2\LoginFlutter-master\build\app\intermediates\compressed_assets\debug\out\assets\flutter_assets\assets\icon, supongo que se quedo abierto algun proceso que apunta ahi, o no debe tener permiso de acceder

Comment: Intenta "./gradlew clean" en su terminal.

Comment: ¿Has probado a actualizar la versión de IOS a la 21?

Comment: ya intenté borrar el directorio pero no se soluciona

Comment: ./gradlew : El término './gradlew' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, archivo de 
script o programa ejecutable.